# Disable hover effect on MUI DataGrid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm struggling on small detail that would be to disable the hover effect of a MUI Datagrid row.

I can't find an easy way to do it, and reading the API documentation didn't help me.

How would you do it ?

```
<DataGrid
            columns={COLUMNS}
            rows={dailyReportItems}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            autoHeight
            onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
            pageSizeOptions={[10]}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            getRowId={(row) => row.date}
            components={{
                NoRowsOverlay: () => (
                    <Stack
                        height="100%"
                        alignItems="center"
                        justifyContent="center"
                    >
                        Aucun résultat
                    </Stack>
                ),
                NoResultsOverlay: () => (
                    <Stack
                        height="100%"
                        alignItems="center"
                        justifyContent="center"
                    >
                        Aucun résultat sur ces filtres
                    </Stack>
                ),
            }}
            sx={{
                ".MuiTablePagination-displayedRows, .MuiTablePagination-selectLabel":
                    {
                        marginTop: "1em",
                        marginBottom: "1em",
                    },
            }}
        />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would probably be to just add CSS to override the `.MuiDataGrid-row`[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) behavior.

For example:

```
<DataGrid
  ...
  sx={{

    ...

    "& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "inherit" // Or 'transparent' or whatever color you'd like
    }
  }}
/>
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-mui-grid-hover-vqcy8x?file=/demo.tsx:386-552

Comment: Infact it works perfectly ! Thank's a lot :)

Comment: For me this didnt work without producing a "glitch" on hover. I submitted an issue here https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11070 if anyone has managed to solve that I'd love to hear!

Answer (score 3):

It seems only targeting .MuiDataGrid-row:hover is part of the way but will leave you with an annoying glitch as seen below.

[image: glitch]

This is because it seems to be adding a 'Mui-hovered' class temporarily which causes said glitch.

Making both transparent fixed it for me with no hover and no glitch.

```
// Neutralize the hover colour (causing a flash)
"& .MuiDataGrid-row.Mui-hovered": {
backgroundColor: "transparent",
},
// Take out the hover colour
"& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover": {
backgroundColor: "transparent",
},
```

Comment: Experienced the same glitch and this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me also, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Comment: I had to make a slight change to this solution, because in my case in Data Grid 6.18.5 there was a background style that took precedence for `.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-row:not(.MuiDataGrid-row--editing):not(.Mui-selected):hover`. I was able to address it by changing the "& .MuiDataGrid-row:hover": selector to "& .MuiDataGrid-row:not(.MuiDataGrid-row--editing):not(.Mui-selected):hover"; I left the other selector as-is